# I can't get a value from a field in a one-to-one relationship, tabularinline

Tags: python, django

How do I get the value from the field in a one-to-one relationship.

The tables Tables and Table are linked using TabularInline. And I want to get a value from a field by OneToOneField relationship. I do it with signals. In this case I'm using post_save.

I get an error "Tables has no data"

```
class Tables(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Table(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
    obj = models.OneToOneField(Tables, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="data")


@receiver(post_save, sender = Tables)
def create(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    print(instance.data)
```

If I write it like this, it returns the old queryset

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Tables)
def create(instance, sender, **kwargs):
print(Table.objects.filter(table__id=instance.id))
```